# Rounding datetime to the nearest second instead returns date rounded to day

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, rounding

When I round my datetime's to the nearest second, it rounds it to the nearest day instead.

I have data with the following timestamps:

```
    timestamp
1   2018-06-01 23:59:59.894110
2   2018-06-01 23:59:59.894110
3   2018-06-01 23:59:59.894110
4   2018-06-01 23:59:59.894110
5   2018-06-01 23:59:59.894110
```

I want to round them to the nearest second to get rid of milliseconds.
So first I convert to datetime object:
`df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')`

And now to round, I run:
`df['timestamp'] = df.timestamp.dt.round('1s')`

And this is what it returns:

```
1   2018-06-01
2   2018-06-01
3   2018-06-01
4   2018-06-01
5   2018-06-01
```

For some reason, it drops the `HH:MM:SS` part.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For some reason, it drops the HH:MM:SS part. What am I doing wrong?

It is not removed, only not displayed, because `HH:MM:SS` is `00:00:00` for all data which are printed.

You can check it:

```
print (df['timestamp'].tolist())
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to be the case. I run the same operation on timestamps like this: 2018-06-01 23:59:59.894110 And it still doesn't show the HH:MM:SS

Comment: @mankojag - `2018-06-01 23:59:59.894110` is rounded to `2018-06-02 00:00:00`, so showed `2018-06-02`. Or not?

Comment: Yes! You're right, my bad. I only displayed .head and .tail of my dataset and didn't look in the middle part. Thank you